# c# check if a windows account is locked out in a specific domain

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to do something that I don't even know if it is possible. 
I have a web application based on C# that runs on a specific server. I want to build a code where the user introduces the domain where the app runs (this server depends on the client, for each client it runs on different servers obviously) and the app returns the local windows user accounts of that domain and information saying if the users are locked out or not.

I've tried to use Win32_UserAccount but it seems to get the users of the network I'm currently using.

Is this possible to do?

Thank you so much
Regards,
Flávio Justino

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
using(PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain"))
{
        using(UserPrincipal usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "username"))
        {
            usr.IsAccountLockedOut(); //Gets if account is locked out
        }   
}
```

You need to add dpendency `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll` for the above code to work.

Comment: It works fine but I'm having a few problems. For example, I tried to replace "domain" with null (so it runs the local server) and "username" with my username, and it worked fine. But I'm trying now to point to the server where the app runs and I get the error Exception: The server could not be contacted.; InnerException: The LDAP server is unavailable.
I don't know how to indicate the domain properly I guess. Imagine that the server where the app is running is: 10.123.123.20\test and the password is test12345. How should I indicate this domain in the ContextType.Domain?

Comment: when using `null ` it might be taking the domain of your local machine. The server must be part of the domain you want to query. If not, you might need to create a separate service on the server to get the result. What do you mean by "point to the server?" are you using the `domain` of the server and calling from your local machine which is part of a different domain?

Comment: RDP onto the box 10.123.123.20 and check computer properties. Or simply contact your administrator if you got one who will be able to provide you withe domain.Check - http://www.elmajdal.net/win7/Joining_Windows_7_To_A_Domain/13-system-properties-after-joining-domain.png

Comment: Or simply login to the server and try `echo %userdomain%` in command prompt. this gives you the domain.

Comment: The echo%userdomain% worked. Ok, so my domain is PTWEB. In the above code I have now: using(PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "PTWEB")). I've published the project in the server within this domain. I tried to put in a textbox the name of some user that are in the domain, to check if it is locked out or not. However I get the error "The server could not be contacted". My computer is not in PTWEB domain but I can access the APP from here, which is in PTWEB domain.

Comment: For your hosted app in IIS try changing the app pool account to `NetworkService`. App pool account `ApplicationPoolIdentity` has limited access.